# C# - ContactFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I always get the problem when I try get my xml from the service directly, I work locally:

> The message of action can not be processed by the recipient because
>   the Contract Filter does not match the EndpointDispatch``er. This may
>   be caused by a mismatch contract (non-matching action of sender and
>   recipient) or non-matching bond / security of transmitter and
>   receiver. Make sure the transmitter and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, eg.
>   Message, Transport, None).

config voor WCF

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SupportCenterDB_EFCodeFirst" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2012;&#xD;&#xA; &#xD;&#xA;         Initial Catalog=SupportCenterDB_EFCodeFirst;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;         Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF.IService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address=""
               binding="webHttpBinding"
               contract="WCF.IService"
               behaviorConfiguration="web" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:52302/service.svc/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>     
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

IService.cs

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "tempuri.org", Name ="Service")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Action= "http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/Ticket/{id}/Responses", ReplyAction ="http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/Ticket/{id}/Responses")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Ticket/{id}/Responses",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    IEnumerable<TicketResponse> GetTicketResponses(int id);

    [OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/Ticket/{id}", ReplyAction = "http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/Ticket/{id}")]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "Ticket/{id}")]
    Ticket GetTicket(int id);

    [OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/CreateTicket", ReplyAction = "http://localhost:52302/Service.svc/CreateTicket")]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "CreateTicket")]
    void CreateTicket(Ticket ticket);
}
```

Service.cs

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode =AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Service : IService
{
    private ITicketManager mgr = new TicketManager();
    public IEnumerable<TicketResponse> GetTicketResponses(int id)
    {
        return mgr.GetTicketResponses(id) ;
    }

    public Ticket GetTicket(int id)
    {
        return mgr.GetTicket(id);
    }

    public void CreateTicket(Ticket ticket)
    {
        mgr.AddTicket(ticket.AccountId, ticket.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `service name="WCF.IService"` should be `service name="WCF.Service"` instead ?

Comment: This doesn't work i still get the same error